# Magento 1.9 get product options value for only the checked

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, configurable-product-options

I want to get the product options value for only the checked product option.
My current code loads all product options values, instead of the checked one.

I use radio buttons for my product options, so I need something to get only the value of the checked one.

Current code:

```
<?php   
foreach($_product->getOptions() as $option) {
    echo 'Option title is: ' . $option->getTitle();
    echo 'Option type is: ' . $option->getType();
    echo 'Option values:';
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you want checkout cart page?

Comment: @PrashantPatel No on the product page